# Loading more comments inverts comment order

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: before]

Tap "2 more comments..."

[image: after]

SE App 1.4.1 / iPhone 5s / iOS 9.2

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

When new comments are detected by the realtime web socket, tapping `{N} more comments` triggers a call to `/posts/{id}/comments` which has a default sort of `creation` but in descending order.  Switching to ascending as it should be.